# 3d plot of Tridimensional parabolic motion

Tags: matlab, plot, physics

I am trying to get a 3D plot of a parabolic motion. I am trying to simulate debris from an airplane falling from a certain altitude. Obviously, the parabolic motion and the absence of other forces is a simplification.
These are the initial conditions.

```
h_0=14325  % m
x0=0 % m
y0=0 m
V_0= 200*.3048 %m/s
gamma = 0.78 %rad
```

Obviously, I want my object to reach the ground.  I created the following code, but the plot is a little strange. I don't understand where or what is wrong

```
g=9.8;
z0= 14325;
x0=0;
y0=0;
V_0= 200*0.3048;
gamma=0.78;
V_0x=V_0*cos(gamma);
V_0y=0;
V_0z=V_0*sin(gamma);

t = linspace(0,2*V_0*sin(gamma)/g);
x=x0+V_0x*t;
y=y0+V_0y*t;
z=z0+V_0z-.5*g*t.^2;

indices=z>=0;
x = x(indices);
y = y(indices);
z = z(indices);

plot3(x,y,z)
hold on
plot3(x0,y0,z0,'ro','MarkerSize',5)
xlabel('Posizione x (m)')
ylabel('Posizione y (m)')
zlabel('Posizione z (m)')
grid on
```

Comment: you got the plot right.  to get the object on the ground you need to change the range of the plot. hint, the limit of t is probably not what you want

Comment: You forgot to multiply by `t` for the linear term in the formula for `z` -> `z0+V_0z*t-.5*g*t.^2`. Also, your total time is the time required for the object to return to the same height it had when launched. The object goes up for less than 100m in less than 5s and than it has to fall down for 14.325 km + 100m .... isn't that height a little too much btw?